# onPause is not being called?

Tags: android, android-camera, onpause

Everything works as expected - I hit the home button or let the screen goes dark and locked, the onPause method would be called.

For some odd reasons my camera app just freezes/force closes when there is an alert dialog popup from the Tasker.  I set up this Tasker to show me the popup everytime I receive a new text message.  Regarding which app I am on, this Tasker popup will be on top of the current app/activity.

**Can someone please tell me why this onPause method is not called?**

I have the following code:

```
private void releaseCamera() {
    // stop and release camera
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCameraPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mCameraPreview);
        mCamera.release();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
        try {
            CameraPreviewLayout.removeView(mCameraPreview);  
            releaseCamera();
            }
        catch (Exception e) {  }          
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the error that you get? Could you post the LogCat log?

Comment: I can't get a logcat as I am not able to connect my phone to the eclipse for some unknown reasons.  I connect my other phone to eclipse for testing, but this phone doesn't have Tasker or network to receive a text message.  Thanks

Comment: then it will be difficult to us for helping you if you dont have any log regarding to your problem

Comment: You could install Tasker on the working phone and create a different kind of Tasker popup, maybe one based on a timer. Without some logcat output this is next to impossible to figure out :-/

Comment: I understand.  I will figure a way to get the logcat.  Thanks all for trying to help